# Installing PIL for anaconda python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I can't figure out how to install PIL on my Mac (Sierra 10.12.4) running Anaconda (conda 4.3.18) python 2.7.10.  Anaconda's default python is 3.5.2, so I'm installing with `pip2`.

```
My-MacBook-ProX:dymax thisuser$ sudo pip2 install PIL
Password:
Checking the installation location...
Getting information about 'PIL'...
2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip2/commands/install.py", line 44, in install
    success = packaging.install.install(project)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/install.py", line 515, in install
    info = get_infos(project)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/install.py", line 309, in get_infos
    installed = list(get_distributions(use_egg_info=True))
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/database.py", line 440, in get_distributions
    _generate_cache(use_egg_info, paths)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/database.py", line 103, in _generate_cache
    for dist in _yield_distributions(gen_dist, gen_egg, paths):
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/database.py", line 88, in _yield_distributions
    yield Distribution(dist_path)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/database.py", line 146, in __init__
    self.metadata = Metadata(path=metadata_path)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/metadata.py", line 219, in __init__
    self.read(path)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/metadata.py", line 323, in read
    self.read_file(fp)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/metadata.py", line 330, in read_file
    for field in _version2fieldlist(self['Metadata-Version']):
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/metadata.py", line 95, in _version2fieldlist
    raise MetadataUnrecognizedVersionError(version)
distutils2.errors.MetadataUnrecognizedVersionError: 2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/bin/pip2", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip2==0.0.1.dev1', 'console_scripts', 'pip2')()
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip2/__init__.py", line 19, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip2/cli_wrapper.py", line 24, in install
    result = pip2.commands.install.install(args.project_list)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip2/commands/install.py", line 44, in install
    success = packaging.install.install(project)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/install.py", line 515, in install
    info = get_infos(project)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/install.py", line 309, in get_infos
    installed = list(get_distributions(use_egg_info=True))
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/database.py", line 440, in get_distributions
    _generate_cache(use_egg_info, paths)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/database.py", line 103, in _generate_cache
    for dist in _yield_distributions(gen_dist, gen_egg, paths):
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/database.py", line 88, in _yield_distributions
    yield Distribution(dist_path)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/database.py", line 146, in __init__
    self.metadata = Metadata(path=metadata_path)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/metadata.py", line 219, in __init__
    self.read(path)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/metadata.py", line 323, in read
    self.read_file(fp)
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/metadata.py", line 330, in read_file
    for field in _version2fieldlist(self['Metadata-Version']):
  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils2/metadata.py", line 95, in _version2fieldlist
    raise MetadataUnrecognizedVersionError(version)
distutils2.errors.MetadataUnrecognizedVersionError: 2.0
```

I get identical error for `sudo pip2 install pillow`.  I also tried with `conda`:

```
My-MacBook-ProX:dymax thisuser$ conda install pillow
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/thisuser/anaconda3:
#
pillow                    4.1.1                    py35_0
```

In Python3 I can import PIL. Python2.7 I still get `No module named PIL`.  Grateful for assistance.  Is my `pip`/`pip2` configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving version

```
 pip install pillow==6.1.0(latest)
```

If Doesn't work try

```
pip list
```

If not listed search location of python

```
which python
```

Search for site-packages folder inside resultant location of 'python' (usually under lib/python3.5/site-packages) and check if PIL present or not(packages are not installing right location)